# Possible to simpify $\arctan(\sqrt{x/y})$ in order to avoid the square root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to simplify an expression to use the least amount of operations possible.

I know that, for example, using the property $\arccos(x) = \frac{1}{2}\arccos(2x^2 - 1)$, it's possible to simplify a possible square root (if $x = \sqrt{y}$, for example.)

I'm currently working on an expression that comes down to the calculation of an $\arctan$ of a ratio of two numbers, something like: $\theta = \arctan(r)$, where $r = \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}$.

Is it possible to simplify this equation with some property (or multiple properties together) so that I can calculate theta as a simpler formula for $r^2$?

Comment: If $\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}=\tan\theta$ then $\cos2\theta=\frac{y-x}{y+x}$.

Comment: There's $\arccos\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=2\arctan x$ for $x\ge 0$. This is basically the same as @J.G. 's comment